# How to get the time difference between two rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
Task    Event               Time
2       opened          "2018-12-14 16:23:49.058707+01"
2       closed          "2018-12-14 16:24:49.058707+01"
3       opened          "2018-12-14 16:25:49.058707+01"
3       Interrupted     "2018-12-14 16:26:49.058707+01"
3       closed          "2018-12-14 16:27:49.058707+01"
```

I need to get the data from the table something like this

```
Task    Difference
2           1
```

The data should be fetched only when there are only 2 events opened and closed.
If there are only 2 events then time difference between abs(closed - opened) should be taken.

I can not figure out figure out how to do it based on Event column

Comment: can there be more than one opened or closed row per task? is so, how should it be handled?

Comment: No, It's not possible. Every time a new task id is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using conditional aggregation.

```
select task
      ,max(case when event = 'closed' then time end) - max(case when event = 'opened' then time end) as diff 
--The aggregation can also be expressed using FILTER as shown below
--,max(time) FILTER(where event = 'closed') - max(time) FILTER (where event = 'opened') 
from tbl
group by task
having count(distinct case when event in ('opened','closed') then event end) = 2
and count(distinct event) = 2
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line ? having count(distinct case when event in ('opened','closed') then event end) = 2
and count(distinct event) = 2

Comment: because every task should only have opened and closed events..it counts the distinct events when it is in one of those values and checks it is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified the very good answer of @VamsiPrabhala

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8f42cc81396e26a4e4434c45e8533236)

```
SELECT 
    task,
    MAX(time) - MIN(time) as difference
FROM times
GROUP BY task
HAVING array_agg(event ORDER BY time) = '{"opened","closed"}'
```

1. Grouping by `task`. But only these tasks that have exactly one `opened` and one `closed` state (in that order). This is checked by aggregating the `event`s
2. Because we know that there are only these two `event`s, ordered by time, the first one (`MIN`) is the `opened` event, the last one (`MAX`) is the `closed` event.

Furthermore:

The difference between two timestamps always gets an `interval` type instead of your expected `integer` of minutes. To get the minutes, you'll need:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM
    MAX(time) - MIN(time)
) / 60 as difference
```

`EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM)` converts the `interval` into seconds. To get minutes, divide it by 60.

Comment: Changed answer (simplified the answer of @VamsiPrabhala)

Answer (score 1):

Vamsi's solution works, but it is too complicated for my tastes.  I would just go for:

```
select task, 
       max(time) FILTER(where event = 'closed') - max(time) FILTER (where event = 'opened') 
from tbl
group by task
having count(*) = 2 and
       min(event) = 'closed' and
       max(event) = 'opened';
```

Or, if we don't want to depend on the string ordering:

```
having count(*) = 2 and
       count(*) filter (where event = 'closed') = 1 and
       count(*) filter (where event = 'opened') = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet **another** option is to break your table into 3 separate derived tables: One for the `opened` event, one for the `closed` event, and one for "other" events (e.g. `interrupted`). Then, you can join those derived tables together to get what you need. For example (using CTEs, although you can of course inline the queries):

```
WITH
    -- sample data
    tbl(Task, "Event", Time) AS
    (
        VALUES
        (2, 'opened',       '2018-12-14 16:23:49.058707+01'::TIMESTAMP),
        (2, 'closed',       '2018-12-14 16:24:49.058707+01'::TIMESTAMP),
        (3, 'opened',       '2018-12-14 16:25:49.058707+01'::TIMESTAMP),
        (3, 'interrupted',  '2018-12-14 16:26:49.058707+01'::TIMESTAMP),
        (3, 'closed',       '2018-12-14 16:27:49.058707+01'::TIMESTAMP)
    ),
    -- derived tables
    opened  AS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE "Event" = 'opened'),
    closed  AS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE "Event" = 'closed'),
    other   AS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE "Event" NOT IN ('opened', 'closed'))
SELECT
    -- uses @S-Man's EXTRACT function to get minutes from a TIMESTAMP value.
    ABS(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (opened.Time - closed.Time)) / 60)
FROM opened
    INNER JOIN closed ON
        closed.Task = opened.task
    -- use LEFT JOIN and NULL to exclude records that have an "other" status.
    LEFT JOIN other ON
        other.Task = opened.Task
WHERE other.Task IS NULL
```